# Transfer a file from host filesystem into Dokku app

Tags: dokku

This should be a simple question but I can't find the solution.

How can I transfer a file from the local filesystem into my Dokku container?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the official [copy-files-to-image](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-copy-files-to-image) plugin to do this.